# How can I find a file open time in C#?

Tags: c#, file, time

This code is not good because the access time does is not updated by all application that actually open or access the file.

```
File.GetLastAccessTime("d:\\a.txt");
```

I want to know when a file is open, just it. I thought that I could find it by reading the last Access Time but it's not working because it is not updated by the application that opens it or by Windows.

Answer (score 2):

from msdn File.GetLastAccessTime() method:

> This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native
>   functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the
>   operating system.

Also check out this article:

> http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx

But if i understood you right your application is accessing the file,if so you can set the last access time when you begin to access it:

```
File.SetLastAccessTime(path, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: thanks,exactly I want to watch a directory and detect any file access like open, modify or delete or... I detect all of theme except Open!
when a file just open and close I can not detect it because the lastAccessTime does not update bay windows or any one else!
I want to use it for this cause...